# Include plain HTML page inside a Play Framework view template

Tags: html, playframework

Is there a way to include a plain html page inside a Play Framework's view template? I have a scenario wherein there is a common view template and in the body of the template, I would like to include certain static html pages. I know that I can include other templates inside a certain template, but I'm not sure if I could include a plain html page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Route to static file in Play! 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792875/route-to-static-file-in-play-2-0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to just make your static HTML a template, eg, create `myStaticPage.scala.html`:

```
<h1>Static page</h1>
<p>This page is static, though it is still a template.</p>
```

Then your view template, myView.scala.html:

```
@(staticPage: Html)

<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>@staticPage</body>
</html>
```

And then in your action that renders the template:

```
def renderMyStaticPage = Action {
  Ok(views.html.myView(views.html.myStaticPage())
}
```

You just need to make sure that your HTML page escapes any `@` symbols with `@@`.

On the other hand, if which HTML page that's being included is more dynamic, then simply load the HTML from the file/database/classloader/whereever it's coming from, eg:

```
def renderMyStaticPage = Action {
  val staticPage: String = // code to load static page here
  Ok(views.html.myView(Html(staticPage))
}
```

Comment: Is the val staticPage String refers to the location file path to where the static HTML is located or is it something else?

Comment: `val staticPage` in that example is just html as a string. Where you get that string is left to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could.

Just put something like that in your routes file:

```
GET /file   controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="html/file.html")
```

Here is a duplicated post: [Route to static file in Play! 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792875/route-to-static-file-in-play-2-0)

Comment: I don't think the poster wants to serve static HTML, rather, they want to load HTML into a template.